# Fantasy book about a reincarnated girl who could see auras

Tags: story-identification, books, reincarnation, romantic-interest

I read this book years ago. It was about a reincarnated girl who could see auras and a guy with his sister who are from her past life. The guy was that reincarnated girl's boyfriend. At the end of the first book she blacks out. That's all I remember.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! Please look at our [guide on how to ask a good story ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/31936) and [edit] your question with any details you remember (such as *how many* years ago you read it).